Using multiple SPI devices without chip select(CS)/slave select(SS)
I recently ordered cheap SPI displays only to find out that the chip select/slave select is not on the pinout of the display.
Since I want to use multiple displays at the same time to show different images and don't want to order new ones, here is my question: Is there a easy way of multiplexing/whatever the data signal(s) so it only reaches the display I want to update? If so, how?
Sorry if that is a dumb question, I am relatively new to the topic and can't find anything useful online.
Edit:  I am talking about the 1.3 TFT Black Board variant.

Edit the question and post a link to the display datasheet so we can understand how it works.

The 1.3" TFT screen uses I2C, instead of SPI. I2C only has a clock (SCK) and bi-directional data (SDA) signal. https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005003200395380.html

@Velvet I don't think it's I2C. This website has more information about the panel and here are instructions to wire it to a Raspberry Pi.

@nanash1 Now that I've read the PDF you've linked, it does seem to be some kind of SPI. Unfortunately they're using typical I2C signal names for their SPI interface.

There is no way you can do anything useful without a CS/SS pin wired to a SPI device, not even with one SPI device on a MCU.
But you can wire each display to any MCU GPIO output and control it as GPIO.
If the displays do not even have a CS/SS or any similar pin to latch or load data in, then they may use some other signaling protocol.
If you need to multiplex signals, then there are multiplexer ICs and also analog muxes can be used for that purpose.

The displays in fact have a CS/SS pin but its soldered so the display is allways on read.. changing the soldering is difficult because i need to desolder a flex cable and more...
my idea was to use a multiplexer to connect the the MOSI and MISO between the main controller and the ONE display i want to talk to at the moment. if i understood right, the clock signal doesnt need to be multiplexed in that case. do you think that works? is there anything specific i need to watch out for when choosing a multiplexer?

@stupidman360: You need to demultiplex the clock signal (to avoid bogus commands) and multiplex the MISO signal (to avoid conflicts between simultaneous drivers).  Nothing special needed for MOSI, you can just fan it out.
